# Does pointer-to-member make sense for a static member?

Tags: c++

The pointer-to-member feature of C++ is interesting and powerful, but I'm wondering if it is or should be limited only to instantiated objects of a class, or if it is okay to point to a static member? The use cases aren't obvious to me for either static or non-static usage of the feature, though it does seem very interesting.

Comment: since static members aren't object-dependent, they are like regular variables.

Comment: You can't make a pointer-to-member from a static member.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pointers to statics are actually "normal" pointers, e.g.

```
class MyClass 
{
  public: 

    static int x;

    static int f(int a)
    {
        return a+1;
    }

};

// ...

int* pint = &MyClass::x; // pointer to static property
int (*pfunc)(int) = &MyClass::f; // pointer to static method
```

Pointers to non-static members are "special" because they need a class instance to dereference a value. They can be *thought of* as "offset of a member inside a class instance" (this is very rough, though, and cannot be applied to method pointers!).

Static members, on contrast, are actually much like namespaced global variables, possibly with restricted visibility. They have static memory addresses, which are independent of class instances — all instances share a single static member.

Answer (score 1):

The following is legal C++11 code.

```
struct X
{
    static void f() {}
    static int i;

    X() = delete;
};

typedef void(*funcPtr)();

int main()
{
    funcPtr g = &X::f;
    int *   j = &X::i;
}
```

There is nothing wrong about taking adresses of static member data and functions. As you can see the class never gets instantiated at any time.